# I am trying to make a custom minecraft start screen singleplayer button but it wont work?

Tags: java, minecraft

```
package skink.ui;

import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiSelectWorld;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.GlStateManager;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;
import skink.Client;

public class MainMenu extends GuiScreen {

    public MainMenu() {
        
    }
    
    public void initGui() {
        
    }
    
    public void drawScreen(int mouseX, int mouseY, float partialTicks) {
        mc.getTextureManager().bindTexture(new ResourceLocation("Skink/background.png"));
        this.drawModalRectWithCustomSizedTexture(0, 0, 0, 0, this.width, this.height, this.width, this.height);
        
        this.drawRect(0, 5000, 5000, 300, 0xff162922);
        
        String[] buttons = { "Singleplayer", "Multiplayer", "Settings", "Language", "Quit"};
        
        int count = 0;
        for(String name : buttons) {
            this.drawCenteredString(mc.fontRendererObj, name, (width/buttons.length)*count + (width/buttons.length)/2f + 8, height - 20, -1);
            count++;
        }
        
        GlStateManager.pushMatrix();
        GlStateManager.translate(width/2f, height/5f, 0);
        GlStateManager.scale(3, 3, 1);
        GlStateManager.translate(-(width/2f), -(height/5f), 0);
        this.drawCenteredString(mc.fontRendererObj, Client.name + " Client " + Client.version, width/2f, height/5f - mc.fontRendererObj.FONT_HEIGHT/2f, -1);
        GlStateManager.popMatrix();
    }
    
    public void mouseClick(int mouseX, int mouseY, int button) {
        String[] buttons = { "Singleplayer", "Multiplayer", "Settings", "Language", "Quit"};
        
        int count = 0;
        for(String name : buttons) {
            float x = (width/buttons.length)*count + (width/buttons.length)/2f + 8 - mc.fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(name)/2f;
            float y =  height - 20;
            
            if(mouseX >= x && mouseY >= y && mouseX < x + mc.fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(name) && mouseY < y + mc.fontRendererObj.FONT_HEIGHT) {
                switch(name) {
                    case "Singleplayer":
                        mc.displayGuiScreen(new GuiSelectWorld(this));
                        break;
                }
            }
            
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    public void onGuiClosed() {
        
    }
    
}
```

everything shows up right its just the buttons wont work, when i click singleplayer its suppost to open up the select worlds screen.

i have been working on this project for a week now and i have speant so many hours and have written thousands of lines of code to get to this point, it would mean the world to me if you spent some time to help me with this error, tysm!

Image of main menu :
[Start menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjbC8.jpg)

Comment: Do you get any error message? How far does the program get in that section before it stops working?

Answer (score 1):

So the mouseClicked event isnt firing when you click the spot? For 1.12.2 Atleast the @Override is called mouseClicked not mouseClick if your not calling that from somewhere else. But idk what version ur on

Also im not sure about this but i think you need to call

```
super.mouseClicked(i, j, k);
```

So if these are the coordinates of your button location --> 0, 5000, 5000, 300 It should look something like this.

```
@Override
protected void mouseClicked(int MouseX, int MouseY, int button) {
    super.mouseClicked(MouseX, MouseY, button);
    if (0 < MouseX && 5000 > MouseX && 5000 < MouseY && 300 > MouseY) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public void mouseClick
```

to:

```
public void onMouseClick
```